# Standard Fiscal Year settings - will this change the behaviour of managed apps?

Tags: managed-package, isv, custom-fiscal-year

A customer that runs our managed app changed from default Gregorian years to Standard Fiscal year starting in March.

**Will this affect any of our managed components and how?**

1. Do formula fields or reports get an incorrect semantic?
2. Will Apex-based Date calculations get wrong results?

In case there might be negative consequences are there any Best Practices to handle that?

Comment: Are there any other Business hours apart from default Gregorian? If yes tell me the scenario. So that i can update you further

Answer (score 3):

As a starting point - from [About Fiscal Years](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=admin_about_cfy.htm&language=en_US)

> ## Considerations When Enabling Custom Fiscal Years
>
> Before enabling custom fiscal year, consider these issues:
>
> - Once you enable custom fiscal years, you cannot disable it. However, you can define custom fiscal years that follow the same Gregorian calendar structure as the Salesforce standard fiscal years.
> - Fiscal years will not be automatically created. The only fiscal years available are those that your organization defines.
> - Custom fiscal years can be enabled only with customizable forecasting, *not* with collaborative forecasting.
> - Enabling or defining custom fiscal years impacts your forecasts, reports, and quotas.
>
>   - When you define a new custom fiscal year, or when you change the length of any fiscal period, all quotas for that year will be lost.
>   - When you define a new custom fiscal year, or when you change the length of any fiscal period, forecasts, forecast history, and forecast overrides are lost. Changing the length of a period may also affect the previous or next fiscal year and reports associated with it. Forecasts for periods before the first custom fiscal year will be saved and can be accessed as usual.
>   - Forecast reports for a period after the last defined fiscal year cannot be grouped by period, only by date.
>   - To ensure your forecast reports have the most updated amounts, view the forecast for the period included in the report before running a forecast report.
> - Your organization will not be able to use fiscal period columns in opportunity, opportunity with product, or opportunity with schedule reports.
> - Opportunity list views will not include a fiscal period columns.
> - When custom fiscal years are enabled, you can't use the `FISCAL_MONTH()`, `FISCAL_QUARTER()`, or `FISCAL_YEAR()` date functions in SOQL.

So, yes, there are impacts on reports and SOQL data functions.

It's a bit difficult to be specific, although someone else may have specific experience with this scenario.

Do you use [Organization](https://www.salesforce.com/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_organization.htm).FiscalYearStartMonth in your Apex? If so you should probably dynamically change to using the [Period](https://www.salesforce.com/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_period.htm).StartDate. You might also find the [FiscalYearSettings](https://www.salesforce.com/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_fiscalyearsettings.htm) useful.

Comment: How would I use the Period SObject? Can I insert it or is it auto-created?

Comment: Period is a child of FiscalYearSettings. Both correspond to the configuration made under Setup > Company Profile > Fiscal Year >Custom Fiscal Year. The Period is populated automatically based on records in your system [Source](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/ForumsMain?id=906F00000009BJgIAM)

Comment: Yes, but none of them is of use when you org only uses Standard Fiscal Year (what I asked for). Then only a few fields are populated in Organization.

Comment: Apologies, I think I've misinterpreted the question.  Is the change "from default Gregorian years to Standard Fiscal year starting in March." just changing the "Fiscal Year Start Month" from January to March?